# Converting a FLOAT into DATE in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

I wanted to know how to properly convert FLOAT value into a DATE?

The data we receive has a value oriented as such: YYYYMM ex. 201911 (today's Year + Month). However, all the values passing under the YYYYMM column signifies the first of the month ex. 201911 = 11/01/2019.

```
RIGHT([DATE],2) + '/01/' + LEFT([DATE],4) AS [DATE]
```

When I try converting it, it doesn't put it in a date format because I tried using it in a DATEADD function and it errored on the field I converted.

Comment: Why are you using a floating point value to store a date in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your value is YYYYMM, then one simple method is to convert to a string and then a date:

```
select convert(date, convert(varchar(255), yyyymm) + '01')
```

Or, use `datefromparts()`:

```
select datefromparts(floor(yyyymm / 100), yyyymm % 100, 1)
```

Comment: The first suggestion you provided worked with my subquery. I didn't know that convert statement was possible. A thousand thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this :

```
DECLARE @Date AS FLOAT;
SET @Date = 201911;

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(CAST(LEFT(@Date,4)  AS VARCHAR(4)) + '/01' + '/' + CAST(RIGHT(@Date,2)  AS VARCHAR(2))  AS DATE) , 103) As CREATEDDATE
```

Will output 11/01/2019